# How to understand "barbershop" in the context of "The Knick"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, word-meaning

Source: "The Knick" Season 01 Episode 02 00:08:25

> **Dr. J.M. Christiansen (who is bald)**: The wealth supporting the Knick is endless. People here want their hospital to be the best. And they're willing to pay. All I have to do is ask. Of course, there are certain obligations that come along with getting what I want.
>
> **Dr. John Thackery**: Such as?
>
> **Dr. Christiansen**: Hiring a new surgical apprentice... How did you come to know Captain Robertson?
>
> **Dr. Thackery**: I did some work with him in Nicaragua.
>
> **Dr. Christiansen**: Now he wants you here?
>
> **Dr. Thackery**: No, that was my idea... You are legitimizing surgery. *Taking it out of the barbershop and into the future* and I want to be a part of it.
>
> **Dr. Christiansen**: You do realize if you choose to join us, the work will be hard and the hours long, the results slow and agonizing, and we will see no shortage of death at our own hands.

[image: screenshot of the relevant moment, including subtitle]

Comment: Need way more context. What's the significance of barbershops in this episode? Is someone here a barber?

Comment: "The barbershops" came out of nowhere, I'm afraid. @gotube

Comment: I added moere context anyway. By the way, Dr. Christiansen was bald. Is this related to "Taking it out of the barbershop and into the future"? @gotube

Answer (score 38, accepted):

A barbershop is now only for cutting hair.  It used to be the place that offered surgery, such as pulling teeth.

The "barber's pole" of red and white swirl represents blood and bandages.

In olden days the surgeon was the barber.  He had to be strong and fast. The doctor was not the surgeon. The doctor told the surgeon where to cut, and the barber-surgeon did it.

So barbershop is completely literal.  It is the places that you would go for haircuts, shaves, and surgery.

Comment: This is why, when a junior doctor in the UK (addressed as "Dr. Smith") becomes a consultant surgeon, and a member of the Royal College of Surgeons, they become "Mr. Smith" or "Mrs. Smith" (note: _not_ "Miss. Smith" or "Ms. Smith").  "Surgeons aren't doctors".

Comment: @MartinBonnersupportsMonica - The [Royal College of Surgeons](https://www.rcseng.ac.uk/patient-care/surgical-staff-and-regulation/qualifications-of-a-surgeon/#:~:text=training%20and%20expertise.-,Why%20are%20surgeons%20in%20the%20UK%20called%20Mr%2FMiss%2FMs,%2FMiss%2FMs%2FMrs.) says 'In most other parts of the world all medical practitioners, physicians and surgeons alike, are referred to as Dr while in the UK surgeons are usually referred to as Mr/Miss/Ms/Mrs.'  I gather that Mx is OK too, these days. Many UK surgeons see the distinction as outdated, and don't insist on it.

Comment: I believe it is/was similar in Australia. As a kid (when living in Aus) after horrifically smashing up my left arm in an incredibly unfortunate incident involving trampolines and air rifles, a few doctors had a go at fixing it up, and eventually they put me under the renowned "Mr. Peano", who cut me up, did his magic, and thanks to him I've been able to use my left arm all my life (and have a spectacular scar too, which you can still barely see!) In that era you'd say the *Mister* sort of reverently. I'd hear the old ladies saying "Oh, Sadie's boy was operated on by *Mister* Peano, uh huh".

Comment: Note that The Knick is set in the early 1900s, long after barbers stopped performing surgery. @gotube is correct that the usage is metaphorical, not literal.

Comment: Interestingly, in the UK "surgery" is also the word for a doctor's office, even though the person who treats you there isn't a surgeon.

Comment: @Fattie "In that era you'd say the Mister sort of reverently." Exactly. A bit like a bouncer. Where everyone is a Doctor, Mister stood out. In my experience in the UK (within the last decade), a lot of surgeons do still go by Mr./Mrs. X, though it's always been clear they're immensely qualified/respected etc.

Comment: @Barmar - A 'surgery can also be a session. A hospital or clinic may hold sessions focused on a particular ailment or part of the body, for walk-in patients, e.g. Dr Smith will hold an eye surgery from 2PM in room 246. Members of parliament hold sessions in the area they represent often called 'surgeries' where residents of the constituency can bring problems and issues or receive advice.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Yes, but those don't have the same contradiction I mentioned.

Comment: excellent insight, @DanSheppard TY

Comment: I guess that 's why in one of Sir Pratchett's Discworld novels the musical fanfare for the barber's guild is called "Shave and a Haircut - no Legs".

Comment: it was because barbers has steady hands and sharp blades.

Answer (score 22):

For hundreds of years, barbers in Europe used to perform surgeries. Moving surgery out of the barbershops and into hospitals represented a huge step forward in medical practice.

So here, Dr. Christiansen is doing something to significantly improve surgical procedures wherever they are. Dr. Thackery is comparing this change to the difference of barbers doing surgeries in barbershops to trained surgeons doing it in dedicated hospital facilities.

Some reading: [Bloodletting: an early treatment used by barbers, surgeons](https://www.healio.com/news/cardiology/20120225)

Comment: I wonder if the reason barbers were doing it was simply pragmatic: they had the sharp razors needed for it.

Comment: @MatthieuM. That's what the linked article indicates